# pagination not working with permalink postname

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I know most of the people have faced with this problem.With pagination the first page is showing correctly and the second page link gets like 'services/paged/2/' -page not found .And my problem is, though it is in wordpress what i am showing on the page is not posts content from a category,There is a table in my database which stores some registration information and that information is to be shown on my website.The query is so normal as we do for php site

```
     select * from registration
```

What I am doing is a normal php pagination ,but when it comes to linking the wordpress pagination does affects.what to do without any change in my permalink custom structure .Please help

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be to add in custom routing for your pagination. Wordpress needs to know that paged/2 refers to pagination and not a page. Currently it doesn't, which is why you're getting a 404. You'll also need to then rewrite your query to use the pagination parameters provided in the query string.

Comment: could you pls make it more specific.how to add in custom routing for pagination

Comment: There isn't one single solution for your problem. Use Google to find out how to do basic pagination using PHP and SQL (without Wordpress), then figure out how Wordpress routing works. There's no quick fix for this.